# Passwords showing up as white (or not at all) in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason password fields are appearing as blank (or white) characters in IE8 for a site I'm working on.

Both these screenshots have a long password entered.  The second one I have highlighted it so you can see it recognizes the characters, they just appear as empty.  I also included the IE debug trace.

Full size - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUd4I.png

[image: Unhighlighted]

Full size - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOkn9.png

[image: Password highlighted]

In other browsers they show up fine.  I have never seen anything like this before, any ideas?

HTML header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Only custom CSS for inputs:

```
body, input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Yep, lets see your CSS for input elements.

Comment: The CSS is shown in the screenshots, it's all Bootstrap 2.1 except one line of custom code (added in edit).  Yes the BG is white, it's the first item listed in the CSS in the screenshots.

Comment: Its most likely Open Sans, try a different font and see if that works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by adding a hack in my CSS to override the input font from Open Sans to Arial:

```
.form-horizontal input {
    *background-color: #ffffff !important;
    *color: #464646 !important;
    *font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

It has to be a character issue with Google Font and IE where the password dots are missing from the font or something like that.

Comment: Perfect!  After an hour of trying to track down this scenario, this "hack" fixed it perfectly!

Comment: Just experienced the same issue - I believe it's related to font-family/font-face only - changing to Arial fixes it.

Comment: Same issue, overriding webfont with a system font fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it

```
<?php echo Form::password('password', NULL, array('title'=>'', 'class' => 'input-block-level', 'tabindex' => '2', 'placeholder'=>'Password', 'title' => 'Password', 'style' => 'font-family:arial, serif;')) ?><!-- the font family arial serif is a fix for IE8 password placeholder text -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - my text on all `input[type='text']` elements was white. Moving the mouse cursor out of the modal `div` caused the text to appear. I suspected `filter` and `transition` CSS rules from Twitter Bootstrap to cause the problem - and it was it. I removed `hide` and `fade` classes from my modal window: `<div class="modal hide fade" />` and it works fine now. Give it a try if your modal is animated.