# MVC with Internet Explorer 8 : Html.PasswordFor shows rectangle symbols

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, razor, internet-explorer-8

I'm having issues with Html.PasswordFor objects on IE8. Instead of it showing a "black circle" for hidden text it would show the "broken rectangle" symbol. Was wondering if this is just a font issue or something? It works on the rest of the IE versions.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: hmm. not really sure how to check since it 's working on the rest of the version. is there a specific src for IE8 when you do a font-face?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199471/passwords-showing-up-as-white-or-not-at-all-in-ie

Comment: What font did you set?